# Problem with adding images in loop in html executed from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying add images in "for" loop

```
<div id="p_0" style="text-align:right">
            <picture style="text-align:right;visibility:visible">

                <img src="~/lib/images/Wisielec1.png" alt="Wisielec" style="width:100px;margin-left:inherit">
            </picture>
        </div>
@for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
    <div id="p_@i" style="text-align:right">
        <picture style="text-align:right;visibility:visible">
           <img id="pi_@i" src="" alt="Wisielec" style="width:100px;margin-left:inherit">
        </picture>
    </div>
    }
```

so in JavaScript I have

```
var images = ['Wisielec1.png', 'Wisielec2.png', 'Wisielec3.png', 'Wisielec4.png', 'Wisielec5.png', 'Wisielec6.png' ];
            document.getElementById("pi_" + j).src = "~/lib/images/"+ images[j];
```

But when I'm loading page there is no images in folder /lib/images visible in Developer tools.
Do I have to attach this folder somewhere so that the pictures are uploaded to the server?
I can see pictures only when I enter the path of a specific picture in html code. In console I have error :
Yes, I'm getting error "Wisielec2.png:1 GET https://localhost:44320/Home/~/lib/images/Wisielec2.png 404

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"there is no images in folder /lib/images visible in Developer tools"* - Can you describe the problem more specifically?  Are you making a specific request for an image which you expect to return a valid image?  What is that requested URL?  Why specifically do you expect there to be an image file at that URL?  What is the server's response?  How have you determined that *the loop* is the problem, as the question implies?  What *specifically* is failing?

Comment: when you reload the page the image will be gone for sure unless there is html / server code which is showing these images. Please provide more information / code like the html markup which displays these images

Comment: Can you give an example of a `src` that works for you?

Comment: Ok I edited post, in first div I'm adding file source directly and it shows on the page and in developer tools in folder "images" but I have more images in that folder that aren't visible on page and also in dev tools

Comment: Did you make sure that `document.getElementById("pi_" + j).src = "~/lib/images/"+ images[j];` does what it's supposed to? Are you getting any console errors? Does the src appear as expected in the inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
"~/lib/images/"
```

Why are you using a `~` at the start of the path?  Notice what it does to the URL:

```
https://localhost:44320/Home/~/lib/images/Wisielec2.png
```

This has nothing to do with the code you're writing, you're simply using an incorrect URL.  If `/Home` is in the root of your website then just use that:

```
"/Home/lib/images/"
```

Or perhaps use a relative path based on where you're calling it from:

```
"../lib/images/"
```

Basically you need to determine what the actual correct URL is for your images and use that.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to it because it worked with ~ in first div, but this actually works now, thanks!

Comment: @Vipp90: If you're using any kind of server-side code or framework then that may be modifying your paths before returning them to the client.  It's always worth looking in your browser's development tools to examine the actual client-side code/markup.